# About JQuery UI Autocomplete and Textbox suggestions.!

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, autocomplete

Im trying to implement an autocomplete component for a textbox. Im using the jquery ui autocomplete plugin, tho it kinda works like a drop-down list more than an auto-complete thing.!

I've seen examples that works like when the user is writing, it shows below some options, but also write the complement of the 1st option to select as a "html placeholder" so it looks like:

|"IM SEARCHING SOMET_" *hing on stack overflow* |

(i know you get the idea)

I need to guide the user on what he's writing, and force him to choose one of the items that I bring up (with json or something), like really auto-"completing" what he's writing. I want something like "selectFirst" attribute on that plugin. It seems like there is nothing like it on it. So, what you guys suggest?

I was thinking like writing some code on the "open" event of the plugin, but Idk where to start. Perhaps there is something out there already done, so I don't have to waste like a week on this.

My code already looks like:

```
$(".destination").autocomplete({
            minLength: 2,
            autoFocus: true, open: function(event, ui){ /* DO THE MAGIC HERE */ },
            source: function (request, response) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "@Url.Action("SearchDestinations", "Json")", type: "POST", dataType: "json",
                    data: { term: request.term },
                    success: function (data) {
                        response($.map(data, function(item){
                            return { label: item.Description, value: item.Description, id: item.Id };
                        }));
                    }
                })
            }
        });
```

Thanks in advance (and sorry if this is too noobish).!

Answer (score 0):

That isn't a terribly common behavior of auto-complete textboxes, and you haven't detailed why you are trying to guide the user into making their selection (how will you know the first choice is always best?).

If you do set up such a feature, make sure to style the text that you default into the box after the user's input in a very different way so that it's apparent to the user what they've typed and what you are suggesting (see how Google Instant does it with their search results by using very light-colored text - also note that Google isn't try to guide your search, but are rather showing you what the Instant Search results are for).  Users may or may not be surprised to see additional text appearing after what they type, and, given that their eyes are focused on the textbox, may be inclined to accept that as their input without considering any other options appearing below which may be better.  You'll want to take both points into consideration when doing user testing.

That being said, you can access the text of the first selectable item in the auto-complete drop-down list with a selector similar to this:

```
$(".ui-autocomplete li:first a").text();
```

Then, using the general JavaScript **substr()** method, you can grab just the text from the selection that comes after what the user entered, and display it in the textbox after the user's input.

Comment: It's is not for sure that the 1st choice is always best.? but the nature of the app is that a choice must be made,

Comment: If you can't guarantee that the first choice is best, then it sounds like you shouldn't set up the app to automatically select a choice for the user.  Also, if your problem is that you need to make sure that a selection was made, you should add useful field validation to the form to make sure the user selects an option, rather than forcing a selection on the user.